# What's the `extends` essence of PHP? How PHP's `extends` implement?

Tags: php, extends

What's the `extends` essence?

```
class Person{
    public $name;
    public $age;

    public function __construct($name, $age)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
    }
}


class Woman extends Person{
    public $hair;
    public function __construct($name, $age, $hair)
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $age);
        $this->hair = $hair;
    }
}
```

The upper given a class extends example. 
I hear about the `extends` essence is copy code from parent class to subclass, I don't know how to verify this.

What's the essence of `extends` when PHP compile ?

See this code snippet:

```
    public function __construct($name, $age, $hair)
        {
            parent::__construct($name, $age);
            $this->hair = $hair;
        }
```

if the extends essence is copy code to mix together, I guess the PHP compile will convert upper snippet to below like this:

```
public function __construct($name, $age, $hair)
{
    $this->name=$name;
    $this->age=$age;
    $this->hair=$hair;
}
```

So what's the essence of extends? how do deal with `parent` keywords?

If show the PHP compile result of the subclass Woman, we can know the extends essence. and also I want to know how PHP implement `extends`'s function.

PHP is a open source language, maybe there are source code can explain.

Comment: Yep, the PHP source code is all on [GitHub](https://github.com/php)

Comment: In your code snippet, it will not copy the code into the new constructor, it will call the parent class constructor as a method call.  It has the same effect, but practically it is separate code.

Comment: How to verify, I really want to know the implement.